# Overwrite a macro constant from a Makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile, macros

Is it possible to overwrite a macro with another value from a Makefile?

Lets say I have a file `a.c` and a `Makefile`.

In the `a.c` file I declare a macro as `#define DEBUG 1`.
I want to pass the value to replace it from the `Makefile` as `CCFLAGS += -D DEBUG -Dvar=1`. However, if I do that, I get a **redefine** warning, and the value maintains the one used in `a.c`.

Is this possible? and also, is this bad practice?

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify your macro definition itself:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
#  define DEBUG 1
#endif
```

Or just remove the definition altogether, and always pass the value from the build system.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible?

It shall be not possible through flags like `-DFOO=bar` as the macro define in command lines comes *before* those in the source code files, thus would be overridden (redefined).

However if you intend to control macro values via compiler flags, you might find the `ifndef` directive helpful. For example:

```
[pengyu@GLaDOS-Precision-7510 tmp]$ cat a.c 
#ifndef TEST
#  define TEST 1
#endif

TEST
[pengyu@GLaDOS-Precision-7510 tmp]$ cpp a.c
# 1 "a.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "a.c"




1
[pengyu@GLaDOS-Precision-7510 tmp]$ cpp a.c -DTEST=2
# 1 "a.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "a.c"




2
```